# Python dataframe:: get count across two columns for each unique value in either column

Tags: python

I have a python dataframe with columns, 'Expected' vs 'Actual' that shows a product (A,B,C or D) for each record

| ID | Expected | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | A | A |
| 3 | C | B |
| 4 | B | D |
| 5 | C | D |
| 6 | A | A |
| 7 | B | B |
| 8 | A | D |

I want to get a count from both columns for each unique value found in both columns (both columns dont share all the same products). So the result should look like this,

| Value | Expected | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 3 |
| C | 2 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 3 |

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` and `value_counts`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Expected':['A','A','C','B','C','A','B','A'],'Actual':['B','A','B','D','D','A','B','D']})
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

output:

```
   Expected     Actual
A   4.0         2.0
B   2.0         3.0
C   2.0         0.0
D   0.0         3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Expected':['A','A','C','B','C','A','B','A'],'Actual':['B','A','B','D','D','A','B','D']})
ecnt = df['Expected'].value_counts()
acnt = df['Actual'].value_counts()
known = sorted(set(df['Expected']).union(df['Actual']))
cntdf = pd.DataFrame({'Value':known,'Expected':[ecnt.get(k,0) for k in known],'Actual':[acnt.get(k,0) for k in known]})
print(cntdf)
```

output

```
  Value  Expected  Actual
0     A         4       2
1     B         2       3
2     C         2       0
3     D         0       3
```

Explanation: main idea here is having separate value counts for `Expected` column and `Actual` column. If you wish to rather have Value as Index of your `pandas.DataFrame` you can do

```
...
cntdf = pd.DataFrame([acnt,ecnt]).T.fillna(0)
print(cntdf)
```

output

```
   Actual  Expected
D     3.0       0.0
B     3.0       2.0
A     2.0       4.0
C     0.0       2.0
```